# How to find application's package Name in visual Studio Wp8.1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have designed one windows phone application and deployed it over windows store.

Before deployment I have seen my package name was something like 44d96a5a-3546-494b-b752-3d36e9e05b63 (hex) but after creating applications package I have found that package name got changed like 123Myname.ApplicationName.

I am looking for a package name in hex as previous one so that I can export database using ISETool.exe ts xd myApplicationPackageName Storagelocatoin

How can I get original PackageName?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Package.appxmanifest.
Switch to Packaging tab.
Package name field.